# How do I use PostgreSQL 9.2 JSON data type in Django?

Tags: json, django, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.2 has native json data type support. How do i create a django model that can use this data type as one of the model fields?

Answer (score 30):

[Nb. A lot happened since the question was posted so I thought updating the answer too - now including new Django-postgresql and PostgreSQL 9.3 information]

**PostgreSQL 9.3**

JSON support in PostgreSQL(see the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-json.html) is becoming more and more interesting. It's now possible to search on the JSON fields as if they were database columns! This support is still basic and not on par with standard column operators (see before), as such it's going to be fidgely to use through Django ORM.

**PostgreSQL 9.2**

The JSON data type is [basically text](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-json.html) in pgSQL 9.2. What's added is JSON validation - useful, but not head turning.

****Django and PostgreSQL JSON**

A recent [Kickstarted backed development](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/mjtamlyn/improved-postgresql-support-in-django) for advanced PostgreSQL support in Django was funded a few months ago. It will include advanced support for the JSON type, but probably only in 9.4:

> The Postgres team have recently merged support for a jsonb datatype - binary stored JSON. It is quite likely that I will delay JSON support until Postgres 9.4 is out and only support the jsonb data type. There are several reasons for this, the most significant being that the current json data type is severly limited in its implementation, lacking even an equality operator. This means that some parts of Django annotation code generate invalid queries (see this report) and also means that a __exact lookup has to be forbidden. To handle all these edge cases properly in Django would result in a huge amount of complexity, and the benefits you gain over just storing json in a text field are actually quite limited. 9.4 is due out towards the end of this year, so as a result JSON fields are likely to only feature in the 1.8 release.

Source: [mjtamlyn blog](http://postgres.mjtamlyn.co.uk/arrays.html)

**[Psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/)** also now supports natively the [JSON field](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html?highlight=json#json-adaptation) (as well as HSTORE).

** DIY in Django **

In django it's pretty easy to create your own model field that uses a special Database type, see [field db_type()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_type).

Please notice that:

1. this would only work under pgSQL - you are limiting your code portability (though you can conditionally return a 'text' type on other databases)
2. you will currently mostly gain only database-side json validation
3. and of course the pleasure of retrieving directly a JSON object!

But be careful that Python do not have /direct/ support for JSON, so you are not really skipping the json dump/load cost in python; you do avoid string conversion - but I haven't checked the internals or benchmarked to see if there is any real difference.

With PostgreSQL 9.3 and following looks like things might become more interesting

You could also start from the [django JSONField](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield) and get a lot of boilercode plate already, simply override the `db_type` method.

What sounds, in my opinion, more interesting and worth a database lock-in (I love pgSql, in any case!), is the option in pgSQL to retun data as a JSON structure using [`array_to_json` and `row_to_json`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-json.html).
This would require a more serious change to querysets though, which sounds out of the scope of your question.

Comment: Can you not index on the fields inside the json type?

Comment: The link below shows an option to allow indexing, basically change it from text to char field
https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield#other-fields

Comment: Had this same question, and a couple more data points:
(1) `django-pgfields` provides wrappers to use the JSON data type, but no native access to Postgres JSON lookup features. 
(2) a kickstarter was fully funded back in February 2014 to implement native Django support for all Postgres data types in `django.contrib.postgres` with a target delivery for Django 1.8. Publicly released code has only progressed to very basic features: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/mjtamlyn/improved-postgresql-support-in-django

Comment: Yes, the Kickstarted project seems, unfortunately, dead: http://postgres.mjtamlyn.co.uk/category/blog.html

Answer (score 13):

As of Django 1.9, [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) is available in the `django.contrib.postgres.fields` module that ships with Django. This field uses PostgreSQL field type [jsonb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) (not json).